# css properties are not affecting <a> link within <li> joomla 3.6

Tags: css, joomla, html-lists

In my css file I have

```
.myclass > ul > li > a {
  display:inline;
  list-style-type:none;
}
```

both this style properties display and list-style-type are not working within "a" tag. However  they are working if placed within "li" which does not serve the purpose because I want links which are aligned horizontally. Please advise what can be done.

```
<div class="myclass"> 
<ul> 
<li><a href="">About Us </a></li>
<li><a href="">About Us </a></li>
<li><a href="">About Us </a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're targeting the wrong elements here - essentially `<a>` has a `list-style-type` of none and is inline already anyway, so you're not seeing anything happen. `list-style-type` is something that will affect the `<li>` rather than the `<a>`:

```
.myclass > ul > li {
  display: inline;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

To help make this a little clearer, you could also try adding a property that would have a visible impact on your `<a>` elements, like color:

```
.myclass > ul > li > a {
  display:inline;
  list-style-type:none;
  color: hotpink;
}
```

Then you'll see that your selector was working - it just wasn't having any impact.

Comment: the a tag has list-style-type none but its not removing the circle or disk which accompanies a unordered list item